# Angular JS removing hash results in 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ngroute

I have removed hash from my angular JS website using below code.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

so my current url http://dev.dummpurl.loc/#/courses is replaced with http://dev.dummpurl.loc/courses.

my problem is browser gives me 404 if I ctrl+f5 http://dev.dummpurl.loc/courses.

is there any possible solution by which I can remove # from URL and at the same time runs if refreshed.

Comment: thats what server side need to be done, just return index.html for every 404.

Comment: How to do that is a question for me. I have tried htaccess but no success!

Comment: you need server side program or mod rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in the head

```
<base href="/">
```

And always return the index html file on request , if you are on to SPA(single page application)